# Wordpress URL Problems After Change it

Tags: permalinks

I have error im my link in my site.

I have 2500 post in old site with link like:-

```
www.domain.com/mm-123.html
```

And now i change to WordPress and change URL to :-

```
www.domain.com/sample-post/
```

Now, The error is when any user open `www.domain.com/mm-123.html` its show him Error 400.

So I need when any user open `www.domain.com/mm-123.html` redirect to `www.domain.com/sample-post/` for all post .

Are there way to do that !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with 301 redirects. There is a nice easy plugin that will allow you to do this.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/

If you want to do it on a little lower level you can edit your .htaccess file with the structure you require. Yoast provides a easy to use generator available here:

https://yoast.com/wp-content/permalink-helper.php

Comment: 301 redirects not good for google, i need redirect to orginal post not to home page

Comment: According to google (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en) 301 redirects are EXACTLY what you should be using to change the url of a post.